# Add method to a Class of the .Net class library in VB.Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, class

I would like to know whether exists a way to add a method inside a class of the .Net framework class library.

Let's say for example that I would like to create a Class/module that adds an `IsEmpty` function in the `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard` Class, is this possibly?, if not, Maybe I can do it in one of the `My` namespace? (`My.Computer.clipboard`)

What alternatives I have instead wrapping the entire class? (and that should be done manualy? that's insane)

Comment: @furkle Is just for cosmetic my code, instead of calling a custom class that holds that "IsEmpty" method I would like to preffer call the default "Clipboard" Class to acces to my inserted method. sorry for my english

Comment: Ah, that's a little different. Matt has what you're looking for.

Comment: @furkle please could you provide a tiny example of how to add a method in the "Clipboard" Class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

> An extension method can be only a `Sub` procedure or a `Function` procedure. All extension methods must be marked with the extension attribute `<Extension()>`. The first parameter in an extension method definition specifies which data type the method extends.

Below is a brief example. (Fair warning, I am a C# developer, but I think this is the correct VB syntax.)

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module MyExtensions

    <Extension()> 
    Public Sub MyFunction(ByVal obj As TypeToAddFunctionalityTo)
        ' functionality here
    End Sub 

End Module
```

Note that for the `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard` class in particular, extension methods won't be of any help. Extension methods allow functions to be added to instance types. In the case of a class that is used statically, such as `Clipboard`, you won't ever have any instances of it.

Additionally, you cannot inherit from the `Clipboard` class because it is defined as `NotInheritable`. Creating a wrapper class is possible, however, I would recommend simply creating a static `MyClipboardUtils` class that works as an addendum/sibling to the built-in class.

Comment: I read that before but is unclear for my, could you provide a tiny example using a .Net framework class library Class?, also time ago I have a similar question (which I can't find) and one guy told that is only avaliable in C# but not VB, but in the examples of the linked url I see VB examples, as I said I'm confused, thanks

Comment: Thanks but I still don't understand how to add it to the "Clipboard" class.

Comment: I added a brief example. However, extension methods allow a function to be added to an instance type. In the case of a static class, such as `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard`, they aren't going to do any good, as you won't ever have instances of the `Clipboard` type.

Comment: So, in other words, the answer to my question is "No, is not possible in your case"?

Comment: Correct, in the case of the `Clipboard` class, extension methods won't help. And you cannot inherit from the `Clipboard` class because it is defined as `NotInheritable`. A wrapper class is possible, however, I would recommend simply creating a `ClipboardUtils` class that works as an addendum/sibling to the built-in class.

Comment: @MattJacobi I feel like it'd be prudent to add a section to your answer explaining that it's impossible to create extension methods for `Clipboard` - anyone who finds this answer might assume that your answer is usable for extending `Clipboard`.